# "top n% this year" stat doesn't care if you've actually used the site in the past year

Tags: discussion, rankings

I was just doing some research for another question and stumbled upon a Stack Overflow profile that had the tag "top 2% this year" next to the profile name. [The user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433417/rectangletangle) hasn't logged in for three years.

It seems like that tag should take into consideration whether someone has actually been on the site in the past year. Is it broken, or does that "top n%" button not mean what I think it should mean? How can you be in the top percentage of all users if you haven't logged in for several years?

That last question is rhetorical. I think I know *how*, but I'm questioning about the validity or usefulness of calling someone a top user if they haven't actually used the site in the past year.

Answer (score 11):

I disagree that activity should be taken into account. I had a look at that user's profile and they get many upvotes for their questions (in other cases, answers may get more upvotes), so their contributions are useful to many people, whether they still participate here or not. So they are still a top user because they provided useful *content* and that's what SE is about.

Why should someone who provided (rather) timeless questions/answers not remain a top user? In contrast, for example, to someone who is quite active, but whose content is not of interest or use for too long? If I have a problem and look it up on SO, to me it matters if the post is helpful, not so much if the author is still active.

Comment: _"Why should someone who provided (rather) timeless questions/answers not remain a top user?"_ - I would say it's because they aren't a user if they don't actually use the site. I appreciate you presenting an opposing view. Thanks!

Comment: Yeh, "top contributor", not "top user".